# Legalization in Pakistan of Documents for Finland

Tags: paperwork, legal, finland, pakistan, embassies

Want to ask how to legalize documents in Pakistan with no consulate or embassy representing Finland here. I looked around everywhere and can't find any answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

From [Finland Abroad](https://finlandabroad.fi/web/pak/frontpage):

> Finland does not have a mission in Pakistan.
>   In consular matters, you can seek advice from the missions of the other Nordic countries or EU countries.

Sweden has the closest bonds with Finland so I'd suggest visiting [that embassy](https://www.swedenabroad.se/en/embassies/pakistan-islamabad/), located in Islamabad.

Some Swedes speak Finnish naturally, but the Danish, Icelanders and Norwegians usually don't.

Comment: There are many Swedish speakers in Finland (it's an official language), but few Finnish speakers in Sweden.  Not that it really matters, since they'll both correspond with you in English.

Comment: @jpatokal I wouldn't say few but I can now see that I used to live in an area with about [10 % finnish speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweden_Finns#Today).

Answer (score 2):

[According to Finland Abroad](https://finlandabroad.fi/web/pak/legalisation-of-documents) you can have your document authenticated for use abroad by:

> Pakistani documents must be legalised at the Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Pakistan. After that they can be sent directly to the competent Finnish authorities, who will decide if they approve the documents or not.

[That being said:](http://honoraryconsulatepakistan.fi/2017/11/17/legalisation-of-pakistani-documents-for-finland/)

> Norwegian Embassy in Islamabad no longer legalises documents destined for Finland

So your best bet is going to be the Swedish representation in your country.